# Android failure delivering ResultInfo Intent attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android

Im trying to pass data from a QR Scanner Activity to another Activity and display the scanned result in the other activity. when I scan QR Code, it returns back to the Other Activity but when I press back it stopped working and gives me this error

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.justinjunias.stockitem/.receiptactivity.CreateReceiptActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.justinjunias.stockitem/com.justinjunias.stockitem.receiptactivity.CreateReceiptActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

caused by this line:

```
qrResult = extras.getString("QRItemtype");
```

This is my QR Scanner activity:

```
public class QRScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //View Objects
    private String itemTypeQR;

    //qr code scanner object
    private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

    private static final int QR_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qrscanner_activity);

        //intializing scan object
        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        qrScan.setOrientationLocked(false);
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }

    //Getting the scan results
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (result != null) {
            //if qrcode has nothing in it
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this, CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                itemTypeQR = result.getContents();
                qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                startActivity(qrResult);
                finish();
            } else {
                //if qr contains data
                try {
                    //converting the data to json
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                    //setting values to textviews
                    Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this, CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                    itemTypeQR = obj.getString("type");
                    qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, qrResult);
                    startActivityForResult(qrResult,QR_REQUEST_CODE);
                    finish();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    itemTypeQR = result.getContents();
                    Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this,CreateReceiptActivity.class);
                    qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, qrResult);
                    startActivityForResult(qrResult,QR_REQUEST_CODE);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //initiating the qr code scan
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }
}
```

And this is the activity which I want to display the QR Scanned result.

```
public class CreateReceiptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.receipt_date)
    TextView date;
    @BindView(R.id.receipt_invoice)
    TextView invoiceNumber;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_receipt_add_item)
    ImageButton addItem;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_receipt_print)
    ImageButton printItem;
    @BindView(R.id.receipt_view_recycler)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.create_receipt_pb_loading)
    ProgressBar pbloading;

    private static final int QR_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    List<ListAutoComplete> autoCompleteList;
    ListAutoComplete listAutoComplete;


    List<ListReceiptItem> receiptItemList;
    ListReceiptItem listReceiptItem;
    ReceiptItemAdapter adapter;
    public String itemType, itemQty, itemPrice, itemDate, itemInvoice, lastInvoice, qrResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_receipt);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        receiptItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new ReceiptItemAdapter(this, receiptItemList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemInvoice = invoiceNumber.getText().toString();
        itemDate = setDate(date);
        date.setText(this.getString(R.string.date, setDate(date)));

        printItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                pbloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                cutStock();
                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateReceiptActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Print Transaksi ?").setPositiveButton("Ya", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("Tidak", dialogClickListener).show();

            }
        });


        addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater li = CreateReceiptActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

                final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_create_receipt, null);
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateReceiptActivity.this);
                builder.setView(v);
                final EditText addItemType = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_type);
                final EditText addItemQty = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_qty);
                final EditText addItemPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_price);
                Button btnSubmit = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_submit);


                final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        Button btnScan = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_scanqr);
                        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(CreateReceiptActivity.this, QRScannerActivity.class);
                                startActivityForResult(i, QR_REQUEST_CODE);
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
                btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        itemType = addItemType.getText().toString().trim();
                        itemQty = addItemQty.getText().toString().trim();
                        itemPrice = addItemPrice.getText().toString().trim();
                        listReceiptItem = new ListReceiptItem(itemType, itemQty, itemPrice, "0");
                        receiptItemList.add(listReceiptItem);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "barang tertambah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        } else if (data != null) {
            if (requestCode == QR_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                    qrResult = extras.getString("QRItemtype");
                if (qrResult == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scan gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!(qrResult == null)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, qrResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void cutStock() {
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        for (ListReceiptItem listreceiptItem : receiptItemList) {
            final String soldItemDate = date.getText().toString().trim();
            final String soldItemInvoice = invoiceNumber.getText().toString().trim();
            final String soldItemtype = listreceiptItem.getType();
            final String soldItemQty = listreceiptItem.getQty();
            final String soldItemPrice = listreceiptItem.getPrice();

            db.collection("watchlist").whereEqualTo("type", soldItemtype)
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                            String id = document.getString("id");
                            String oldqty = document.getString("qty");
                            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(oldqty) - Integer.parseInt(soldItemQty);
                            String newQty = String.valueOf(i);

                            Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("qty", newQty);
                            db.collection("watchlist").document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge());

                            ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            Map<String, Object> receiptItem = new HashMap<>();
                            receiptItem.put("invoice", soldItemInvoice);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("date", soldItemDate);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("type", soldItemtype);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("qty", soldItemQty);
                            list.add(receiptItem);
                            receiptItem.put("price", soldItemPrice);
                            list.add(receiptItem);


                            final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            firebaseFirestore.collection("sales").add(receiptItem).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                    Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Berhasil mencetak transaksi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(soldItemInvoice) + 1;
                                    String newInvoice = String.valueOf(i);
                                    invoiceNumber.setText(newInvoice);
                                    pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Gagal mencetak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Barang tidak terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                        pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateReceiptActivity.this, "Barang tidak terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void getTypeList() {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference documentReference = db.collection("watchlist");
        documentReference.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                                String type = document.getString("type");
                                listAutoComplete = new ListAutoComplete(type);
                                autoCompleteList.add(listAutoComplete);
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public String setDate(TextView view) {

        java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();//getting date
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");//formating according to my need
        String date = formatter.format(today);
        view.setText(date);
        return date;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a "startActivityForResult(i, QR_REQUEST_CODE);" in CreateReceiptActivity, I do not see any getIntent in scanner activity. Exactly what it is requesting to perform (and how).   Also in scanner activity "onActivityResult" is response to which intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your QRScannerActivity, you are using startActivity() instead of startActivityForResult() in only "if" condition.

so try to use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() as below:

```
if (result.getContents() == null) 
{
    Intent qrResult = new Intent(QRScannerActivity.this, CreateReceiptActivity.class);
    itemTypeQR = result.getContents();
    qrResult.putExtra("QRItemtype",itemTypeQR);
    startActivityForResult(qrResult);
    finish();
}
```

And in your CreateReceiptActivity try to use if condition like extras != null  && extras.containsKey("QRItemtype") as below:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        } else if (data != null) {
            if (requestCode == QR_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if(extras != null && extras .containsKey("QRItemtype")){
                    qrResult = extras.getString("QRItemtype");
                    if (qrResult == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Scan gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (!(qrResult == null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, qrResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You are passing bundle from QRScannerActivity to CreateReceiptActivity and try to get it in onActivityResult() of CreateReceiptActivity
but my suggestion is that try to get "Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();" in onCreate() of CreateReceiptActivity because i think that
you dont want anything from "Intent data" of onActivityResult() of CreateReceiptActivity like below:

```
else if (data != null) {
    if (requestCode == QR_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    }
}
```

but you are using

```
else if (data != null) {
    if (requestCode == QR_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    }
}
```

so first decide whichever you want to use. thanks

Comment: I forgot to change that one, but that one is when result == null, the other if condition I already put startactivityforresult.

Comment: thanks for the advice ! now I put my scan inside the onCreate. but I have a couple question, after I scan the qr code and intent back to CreateReceiptActivity, the alertdialog closed so I need to press button to open it again. how if I want the alertdialog still opens when intents back ?

Comment: you are taking alertdialog in addItem.setonclicklistener but instead of that take it globally and you can write any condition that if its true or false then alertdialog.show()